# Prepositions and adverbs of direction and location

Tags: meaning, preposition, adverb, place-name

I’m a bit confused by the German prepositions and adverbs expressing direction or location.  I know that “unter”, “vor”, “auf”, “in” and “aus” are prepositions which require a noun, while “unten”, “vorn/e”, “oben”, “drin” and “draußen” are corresponding adverbs which describe a location and are self-sufficient.  That much is clear to me.

However, there are many other prepositions and adverbs which seem to have the same meaning.  For example, beside “unter” and “unten” there are also “hinunter” and “unterhalb.”  How are they different from “unter”?

And beside “”auf” and “oben” there are also “obenauf,” “rauf,” “oberhalb, "hinauf," "herauf," "rüber" and “über.”   Likewise beside “in” and “drin” there are “innen,” “inner,” “hinein,” “herein,” “drinnen,” “innerhalb” and “rein.”  And beside “aus” and “draußen” there are also “außen,” “heraus,” “hinaus,” “raus,” “außer” and “außerhalb.”

Could you, please, help me make sense of this zoo? :) Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unter**, **über**, **in**, **aus** and **außer** are prepositions. *Unter* can also be an adverb meaning *less than*, but that's not the case here. The other words from your list are all adverbs.

You can use those adverbs to narrow down the meaning of the included preposition. For example **unterhalb** narrows down the meaning of the preposition **unter**:

> **Unter** den metrischen Schrauben waren zöllige.

***Among*** the metric bolts were imperial ones.

***Below*** the metric bolts were imperial ones.

> **Unterhalb** de**r** metrischen Schrauben waren zöllige.

***Below*** the metric bolts were imperial ones.

The adverbs *oberhalb*, *innerhalb*, *außerhalb* work very similar.

> Es gibt **oberhalb** dieser Hütte keine weitere.

*There's no other lodge **above** this one.*

> Er arbeitete **innerhalb** seiner Möglichkeiten.

*He worked **within** his potential.*

> Er kommt von **außerhalb** der Stadt.

*He comes from **out of** town.*

---

The adverb **hinunter** is used with verbs of movement.

> Sie bretterte den Skihang **hinunter**.

*She hurtled **down** the ski slope.*

The adverb **herunter** is pretty much the same, but the view is different: *hin-* means she's moving away from you, while *her-* means she's approaching you. That's the same for *hinauf* and *herauf*, *hinein* and *herein*, *hinaus* and *heraus*.

> Geh **hin**!

*Go **there**!*

> Komm **her**!

*Come **here**!*

The adverb **rauf** is a shortcut of **herauf**, **rüber** a shortcut of **herüber**, **raus** a shortcut for **heraus**. In some German dialects, **nauf** as a shortcut for **hinauf**, **nüber** as a shortcur of **hinüber** and **naus** as a shortcut of **hinaus** also exist.

---

The adverbs **innen** and **außen** mean something is on the inside or the outside of barrier, e.g. a wall or window.

> Die Bedienung erfolgt von **innen**.

*Operation is done from **inside**.*

> Die Scheiben sind **außen** total verdreckt.

*The window panes are completely dirty **on the outside**.*

The adverbs **drinnen** and **draußen** are used in a similar fashion, but it's not focusing on a barrier.

> Die Kinder spielen **draußen**

*The kids play **outdoors**.*

> Du bist in der Mannschaft **drin(nen)**.

*You are **in** the team.*

---

**Obenauf** is a tricky word with mostly idiomatic use.

> Er war wieder **obenauf**.

*He was **okay** again.*

Comment: There are parallels with *hereafter*, etc in English (many of which are widely treated as archaic nowadays).

Comment: Thank you very much!  This was very helpful.  
But I still have some questions.  Are “oberhalb” and “über” interchangeable?  And “drin” and “drinnen”?
If I were standing at the bottom of the slope, and she was hurtling towards me, would it be, “Sie bretterte den Skihang herunter”?  And if I were watching the action from the side, and she hurtled by me, first approaching and then moving away, would it be just “unter”? 
I saw “herunterfallen” used when a person dropped a photo camera, but the camera was falling from him, so why not “hinunterfallen”?

Comment: I frequently saw “hinausgehen” used when a  person said he went out of his house, not moving away or towards himself obviously, so why not just “ausgehen”?
And I saw “herausgehen” used when a projectile which had broken into the house was exiting it, making another hole in the wall.  Why not use “hinausgehen” for this exiting movement, since it was now moving away from the observers and the house?
Thank you very much again for your help!  It’s greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Oberhalb* and *über* aren't interchangeable, because über is a preposition, while *oberhalb* is an adverb. But as with *unterhalb* and *unter*, there are sentences where such an adverb of position plus a genitive attribute drops nicely into the place of a prepositional object of place. *Drin* is just a shorter form of *drinnen*.

Comment: You can choose *hin-* and *her-* adverbs (and verbs) of direction freely. But it makes more sense to choose them so the person listening gets the right impression. If the action has both, you had to decide on which part you want to focus. You can't use for the word *unter* at that place. Same for *ausgehen*.

Comment: *Sie geht hinaus.* means the observer is inside the object left by her. *Sie kommt heraus.* means the observer is outside the object left by her. *Sie geht heraus* and *Sie kommt hinaus* are odd and only found in sloppy speech.